# problema ejecutar una setInterval() dentro de un while en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito ejecutar un setInterval() pero al intentar hacerlo dentro de una ciclo while el seeInterval() nunca se ejecuta. Soy principiante en javascript asi que no se cual es el motivo.

El codigo que intento ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
var i = 0;

while(i < 5){

    var c = 0;

    var t = setInterval(function(){
      c++;
      if(c==5){
        clearInterval(t);   
      }
     },2000);

    i++;
}
```

Cual es el metodo para crear un time.sleep() dentro de un ciclo while en javascript?

Comment: Cuéntanos qué quieres hacer a lo mejor el while no es necesario

Comment: Quiero hacer lo que describo en la pregunta.. o sea dormir un ciclo durante 5 segundos...

Comment: @JhonatanZu no se puede bloquear un `while` por lo que si te parece, podemos sugerirte otra forma de realizar el bucle.

Comment: @Marcos   Si, mira disculpa mi ignorancia, es que vengo de Python y en ese lenguaje es normal dormir ciclos while.. por eso me sorprende que en javascript no se pueda.. ¿como puedo hacer que en medio de un ciclo espere un tiempo antes de pasar al siguiente ciclo?.. me parece increible que no haya una manera

Comment: @JhonatanZu ¿estas trabajando en `Nodejs`?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocar el while en una función async

Y dentro del while colocas el comando sleep

```
async function someFunction() {
while(condition) {
await sleep(5000);
}
}
```